# Unable to cast to System.String in Selenium 2.0 Webdriver NUnit Test Case

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Below I'm debugging and throwing an exception on purpose to find out the value of a JavaScript call from WebDriver.  How can I cast the jQuery call so I can print a string (based on the number of tr tags in my table with id of "viewtable") in my exception message?  I imagine this has absolutely nothing to do with the C# code.  I bet the driver can't execute the jQuery call properly, but I don't know the correct syntax.

**Exception thrown by NUnit:**

```
Selenium.ProductPricing.TheUntitledTest:
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'.
```

**Environment:**

- Class Library project is called Selenium.sln/Selenium.csproj
- project referencing NUnit dll & Selenium C# client drivers including WebDriver dll files
- project has one class class called ProductPricing.cs
- running class library dll in NUnit 2.6

**Test Case C# code:**
(search for "BAD!" below)

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using Selenium;
using System.Text;
using System;

namespace Selenium
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ProductPricing
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        private string baseURL;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseURL = "http://buyemp.qa.xxx.com/";

            ISelenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseURL);
            selenium.Start();

            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }

        [Test]
        public void TheUntitledTest()
        {
            //String var_skip_product = "false";
            String var_admin_user = "coders@xxx.com";
            String var_admin_pass = "notsure";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/admin");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys(var_admin_user);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).Clear(); 
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(var_admin_pass);
            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type=\"submit\"]")).Click();            
            driver.WaitForElement(By.LinkText("Products"));
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Products")).Click();
            String var_product_row = "24";  // force script to start on row 24/25

            //// ERROR: Caught exception [unknown command [getTableTrCount]]
            // Command: getTableTrCount | Target: viewtable | Value: var_table_row_count (user extensions don't work in WebDriver)
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

            // this one throws an exception with value 22 - GOOD!
            //int x = Convert.ToInt32((string)js.ExecuteScript("return '22'"));

            // this one throws an exception with the cast exception - BAD!
            int x = Convert.ToInt32((string)js.ExecuteScript("return $('#viewtable tr').length"));

            // explicitly throwing Selenium exception so we can debug this code in NUnit
            throw new SeleniumException(x.ToString());

            // Command: storeText | Target: //a[@title='last page']/text() | Value: var_page_total_text
            // Conversion: String var_page_total_text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@title='last page']/text()")).Text;
            String var_page_total_text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@title='last page']")).Text;

            //// ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [getEval]]
            // Command: eval | Target: javascript{storedVars['var_page_total_text'].substring(1,storedVars['var_page_total_text'].length-1)}
            //int var_page_total = Convert.ToInt32(var_page_total_text.Substring(1,var_page_total_text.Length-1));           

        }    

        private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(by);
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem you're experiencing has **everything** to do with your C# code. Ints can't be cast to strings directly, and `IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript()` returns an `object` coerced into the correct type. In this case the `.length` property from your jQuery selector returns a JavaScript numeric type, so the C# language bindings return an int from the `ExecuteScript()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from the exception I'm assuming that `ExecuteScript` is returning an `int64` for `$("query").length` and a `string` for `$("query").html()`.

So you might want to try this:

```
string x = js.ExecuteScript("return $('#viewtable tr').length").ToString();
```

or if you prefer a number:

```
long x = (long)js.ExecuteScript("return $('#viewtable tr').length");
```

Not sure about the second one but the first one should work.

Comment: This is exactly correct. You can't cast a numeric value directly to a string.

Comment: Thanks MUCH!  How is .ToString() different from casting to (string)?

Comment: second one works btw and that's the type I want, so I can use it in a loop

Comment: Yup, (string) is simply casting the object into a string, which will fail if the object is not a string type. ToString tells the object to return a string version of itself

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a bug, or else Selenium doesn't like the assignment of the selector.  If you have an idea, let me know.  Unless the syntax I'm using for the appended tr in the selector isn't supported in the version of jQuery on this site.

Although that's not the case because the Selenium IDE user extensions custom command below works fine.

```
function jQuery(selector)
{
    return selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().jQuery(selector);
}

Selenium.prototype.doGetTableTrCount = function(tableName, varStore) { 

    this.doStore(jQuery('#' + tableName + ' tr').length,varStore);
};
```

**This works:**

```
IWebElement webElement = (RemoteWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("return $('#viewtable').get(0);");
string jQuerySelector = "arguments[0]";
string x = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return $(" + jQuerySelector + ").html()", webElement);
throw new SeleniumException(x);
```

**This works:**

```
string x = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return $('#viewtable').html()");
throw new SeleniumException(x);
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
IWebElement webElement = (RemoteWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("return $('#viewtable tr').get(0);");
string jQuerySelector = "arguments[0]";
string x = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return $(" + jQuerySelector + ").length", webElement);
throw new SeleniumException(x);
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
string x = (string)js.ExecuteScript("return $('#viewtable tr').length");
throw new SeleniumException(x);
```